How to make tag_invoke CPO deal uniformly with types matching a meta-predicate/concept and with those types wrapped in reference_wrapper?
(I'm mostly interested in a c++17 solution, even though you see me using std::unwrap_ref_decay; just imagine I've copied and pasted the possible implementation in my C++17 code. On the other hand, I'm also curious about how you'd address the matter in c++20.)
Say I have a customization point object, cpo, defined like this,
constexpr struct CPO {
    template<typename T>
    constexpr auto operator()(T&& t) const -> decltype(tag_invoke(*this, std::forward<T>(t))) {
        return tag_invoke(*this, std::forward<T>(t));
    }
} cpo{};

and a template class like this
template<std::size_t N>
struct Foo {
    constexpr int& cpo() {
        return i;
    };
    constexpr int const& cpo() const {
        return i;
    };
    int i;
};

One way all instantiations of Foo can implement the customization point is like this (yeah, this is actually wrong as we don't want to make a copy and we want to return a reference, but bear with me, the attempt you see in the following does that):
template<std::size_t N>
constexpr auto tag_invoke(CPO, Foo<N> foo) {
    return foo.cpo();
}

But what if I want to be able to pass a std::reference_wrapper<Foo<N>> to cpo?¹ After all, an object constructed via std::ref(foo)/std::cref(foo), with foo being a Foo<N> is supposed to behave like a Foo<N>&, so I would expect that the customization of cpo for Foo<N> also accepts a Foo<N> wrapped in a std::reference_wrapper.
However, the fruit doesn't seem to hang so low.
If cpo was implemented for one (or more) specific instantiation(s) of Foo,
constexpr auto tag_invoke(CPO, Foo<2> foo) {
    return foo.cpo();
}

then passing a std::reference_wrapper<Foo<2>> would be ok, because it is convertible to the concrete type Foo<2>
int main() {
    Foo<2> foo;
    cpo(foo);
    cpo(std::move(foo));

    auto r = std::ref(foo);
    cpo(r);
    cpo(std::move(r));

    auto cr = std::cref(foo);
    cpo(cr);
    cpo(std::move(cr));
}

However, as soon as I generalize the implementation (e.g. I go back to the tag_invoke templated on N), the main above fails to compile when cpo is passed a reference wrapper argument.

My attempt to solve this problem consisted in defining an is_foolike_v meta-predicate, and to use it in the definition of tag_invoke to SFINAE-in only those types that are Foo<N> or a std::reference_wrapper<Foo<N>>; in the body, I use std::unwrap_ref_decay_t and std::forward to pefect forward the return value back to the caller:
template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<is_foolike_v<T>, bool> = true>
constexpr decltype(auto) tag_invoke(CPO, T&& foolike) {
    return std::unwrap_ref_decay_t<T>(std::forward<T>(foolike)).cpo();
}

which seems to work as intended, based on these tests:
int main() {
    Foo<2> foo{3};
    assert(cpo(foo) == 3);
    assert(cpo(std::move(foo)) == 3);

    auto r = std::ref(foo);
    foo.i = 4;
    assert(cpo(r) == 4);
    assert(cpo(std::move(r)) == 4);
    cpo(r) = 5;

    auto cr = std::cref(foo);
    assert(cpo(cr) == 5);
    assert(cpo(std::move(cr)) == 5);
}

but it still partly hardcodes the knowledge of the fact that foolike could be a std::reference_wrapper. Yeah, there's not really an if constexpr on that condition, because that's handled via std::unwrap_ref_decay which as a no-op for non-std::reference_wrapper types...
But still I'd like to know if I'm overcomplicating the matter.
Furthermore, here's a more complicated but also more real-world scenario, where Foo is actually std::array, and it customizes the CPO to extract the first element (you see that this very CPO could be customized by std::tuple as well). In this case, the testing code is this,
int main() {
    std::array<int, 1> arr{3};
    assert(cpo(arr) == 3); // <---
    assert(cpo(std::move(arr)) == 3); // <---

    auto r = std::ref(arr);
    arr[0] = 4;
    assert(cpo(r) == 4);
    assert(cpo(std::move(r)) == 4);
    cpo(r) = 5;

    auto cr = std::cref(arr);
    assert(cpo(cr) == 5);
    assert(cpo(std::move(cr)) == 5);
}

but the customization of the CPO written in line with the previous one I wrote,
template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<is_arraylike_v<T>, bool> = true>
constexpr decltype(auto) tag_invoke(CPO, T&& arraylike) {
    return std::get<0>(std::unwrap_ref_decay_t<T>(std::forward<T>(arraylike)));
}

causes a compile failure if I try assigning cpo(arr) = 3.
Changing the body to
    if constexpr (is_reference_wrapper_v<std::decay_t<T>>) {
        return std::get<0>(std::unwrap_ref_decay_t<T>(std::forward<T>(arraylike)));
    } else {
        return std::get<0>(std::forward<T>(arraylike));
    }

fixes it, but it feels clunky. This last example is here.

(¹) No, I don't want to explicitly implement the customization point for std::reference_wrapper, because there's many different CPOs defined for Foo, and some are binary and others are ternary, unlike the unary cpo defined above, so that would force me to implement each CPO for all combinations of std::reference_wrapper/non-std::reference_wrapper.

Is it intentional that you are copying foo? If you want foo.cpo() to be called on a const ref then Foo::cpo should be const qualified

@Caleth, sorry I've rushed a bit in writing the question, so it might lack some details. If you are referring to the first two definitions of ŧag_invoke where Foo<> is by-value, that's not intentional. In reality, Foo is pretty much like std::array, and the CPO essentially calls std::get<0> on the Foo<>.

std::decay_t<std::unwrap_ref_decay_t<T>>(std::forward<T>(foolike)) is a copy too

@Caleth, I think the updated question should have all necessary details. I haven't gone through your answer yet though.

You can easily simplify by doing more of the work in the parameter to enable_if, eliminating all of is_foolike.
template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<is_foo_v<std::decay_t<std::unwrap_ref_decay_t<T>>>, bool> = true>

You also probably want to forward as the unwrapped type, rather than forward into a copy.
return std::forward<std::unwrap_ref_decay_t<T>>(foolike).cpo();

Godbolt link demonstrating lack of copying.

If edit your code to use std::array instead of Foo, and customize cpo to return the first element of the array, it allows compiling cpo(std::array<int, 1>{3}) = 4;, but it shouldn't because that's a reference to a temporary. See here.

Shouldn't it? get<0>(std::array{3}) is valid, and gives you an int&&

But returning int&& means to return an rvalue, so you can't assign to it, right? I'm ok with cpo(std::array{3}); to be valid, because std::get<0>(std::array{3}) is valid; but cpo(std::array{3}) = 3; should be invalid because std::get<0>(std::array{3}) = 3; is invalid.

I might have found a solution in which I don't need an explicit if constexpr. (Complete example here.)
The trick is to append && or & to std::unwrap_ref_decay_t<T> depending on whether the deduced T is T&& or T& respectively, and to append const as well, if T is const. This will leave the behavior unchanged for when T is truly a std::reference_wrapper, and will fix the behavior for when T is just a std::array.
To append & or &&, I've written the following meta-function:
template<typename T, typename W>
struct copy_ref_const {};

template<typename T, typename U>
struct copy_ref_const<T&&, U> {
    using type = U&&;
};

template<typename T, typename U>
struct copy_ref_const<T&, U> {
    using type = U&;
};

template<typename T, typename U>
struct copy_ref_const<T const&&, U> {
    using type = U const&&;
};

template<typename T, typename U>
struct copy_ref_const<T const&, U> {
    using type = U const&;
};

template<typename T, typename U>
using copy_ref_const_t = copy_ref_const<T, U>::type;

With this in place, the customization of the cpo can be written as follows,
template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<is_arraylike_v<T>, bool> = true>
constexpr decltype(auto) tag_invoke(CPO, T&& arraylike) {
    return std::get<0>(std::forward<copy_ref_const_t<T&&, std::unwrap_ref_decay_t<T>>>(arraylike));
}

Here's the test:
int main() {
    {
        std::array<int, 1> arr{2};

        static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(cpo(std::move(arr))), int&&>);

        cpo(arr) = 3;
        assert(cpo(arr) == 3);
        assert(cpo(std::move(arr)) == 3);

        auto r = std::ref(arr);
        arr[0] = 4;
        assert(cpo(r) == 4);
        assert(cpo(std::move(r)) == 4);

        cpo(r) = 5;
        auto cr = std::cref(arr);
        assert(cpo(cr) == 5);
        assert(cpo(std::move(cr)) == 5);
    }
    {
        std::array<int, 1> const arr{2};

        assert(cpo(arr) == 2);
        assert(cpo(std::move(arr)) == 2);

        auto r = std::ref(arr);
        assert(cpo(r) == 2);
        assert(cpo(std::move(r)) == 2);

        static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(cpo(r)), int const&>);
        auto cr = std::cref(arr);
        assert(cpo(cr) == 2);
        assert(cpo(std::move(cr)) == 2);
    }
}


Just FYI, you've remade C++23's std::forward_like, so best to stick with the same naming IMO (vs. copy_ref_const)

@ildjarn, can you show me how you'd use it?

@ildjarn, then copy_ref_const is not equivalent to std::forward_like, because if I barely substitute it, it doesn't work (not even if I copy the implementation form cppreference).
